# Is it possible to spoof evil.js as an image to thwart hotlink?

Tags: hotlinking

I doubt this is possible, but I am curious if anyone knows a way to spoof/inject evil.js library instead of an image to sites that attempt to hotlink. I tried a couple things including making a `test.png.js.php` to send `Content-Type: image/png` alongside, some stuff with `data:image/png`, but nogo either way. Perhaps there is some kind of htaccess or DNS mask that could do this? Or perhaps something that could better spoof MIME?

Again, I highly doubt anything can do this, and this is a quite stupid question in all regards of how browsers work, but figured I would ask :) Looking forward to pwning some scrapers. Thanks for your time!

Comment: stuff your script into a subdir, name it "kittens.jpg", then tell Apache that .jpg files in that subdir are actually php scripts. so `http://example.com/death_to_bots/kittens.jpg` will LOOK like an image, but be a script.

Comment: @MarcB Hmm thought that too, did you try it yet? Just tried a few ways on that thought. Chrome is moaning about MIME on this end still -- maybe im mis-understanding the SetHandler or if that is even the best directive to use in this case.

Comment: How are the sites going to hotlink the images? If it is something like `<img src = "image.png">` , I doubt that it is going to work. Otherwise you could have a look at JS + JPEG polyglots: https://hiddencodes.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/hide-javascript-inside-jpeg-file/